# How to append a tab to the end of every line in a text file

Tags: linux, sed, awk, text-processing

I have a text file that has the following format :

```
FirstName   LastName  
Georges     Bernard
Henry       Grey
```

FirstName is separated from the second name by a tab character (\t).
I want to append to every line in the file an age field (it should also be separated from the Lastname field by a tab character).

the end file should look like :

```
FirstName    LastName    Age
Georges      Bernard     20
Henry        Grey        20
```

Comment: Where is the Age field coming from?

Comment: Where do you get the age from?

Comment: @JS I want to provide a constant number for the age field, a constant string as input. that input should be appended to all lines.

Comment: The age should be entered manually by the user. for example :           TabAppender "\t20" myFile.txt

Comment: @ctn I want to have the tab followed by a string. would this work ? sed 's/$/\t20/'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{$0=NR>1?$0"\t20":$0"\tAge"}1' myFile.txt
```

With `sed`:

```
sed '1s/$/\tAge/;2,$s/$/\t20/' myFile.txt
```

#### Demo:

```
$ cat myFile.txt
FirstName   LastName  
Georges     Bernard
Henry       Grey

$ awk '{$0=NR>1?$0"\t20":$0"\tAge"}1' myFile.txt
FirstName   LastName    Age
Georges     Bernard     20
Henry       Grey        20

$ sed '1s/$/\tAge/;2,$s/$/\t20/' myFile.txt
FirstName   LastName    Age 
Georges     Bernard     20
Henry       Grey        20
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
age="${1:?must supply age as argument 1}"
shift
sed "s/$/       $age/" "$@"
```

Where the sequence of spaces represents an actual tab in the source code.  There are ways to get tabs into the source without using an explicit tab, such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
age="${1:?must supply age as argument 1}"
shift
sed "s/$/"$'\t'"$age/" "$@"
```

Both versions of the code expect the 'age' argument in `$1` and accept zero or more file names to be processed (processing standard input if no file name is given).